# how to use multi level user login in codeigniter ?

Tags: codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
    if($this->input->post('login'))
    { 
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      $this->db->select('firstname,password');
      $this->db->from('client');
      $where = "firstname='$username' and password = '$password'";
      $this->db->where($where);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      $result = $query->result_array();
      $num = $query->num_rows();
      if($num >'0')
      {
        $this->db->select('firstname,password,client_id');
        $this->db->from('client');
        $where = "firstname ='$username' and password = '$password'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $this->session->set_userdata('client_id',$result);
        $Session = $this->session->set_userdata('user_type',$result);
        if($session == true)
        {
          redirect('/admins/home');
        }
        else
        {
          redirect('/partner/home');
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Wrong username or password! </p>";
      }
    }
  ?>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="login">
  </form>
```

This might be duplicate question. Here, I have a table in my database having name client. In this table I m declare a column name user type. I want to login according to user type. for example if my user type is admin then only those user can login who having user type admin similarly if user type is partner then only partner can login. So, how can I do this ? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what is the column_name which shows user is admin or partner?

Comment: column_name is user_type @Shihas

Comment: In `user_type` column you are saving value as admin and partner right?

Comment: yes, @Shihas I am saving value as admin and partner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if($this->input->post('login'))
{ 
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      $this->db->from('client');
      $this->db->where('firstname',$username);
      $this->db->where('password',$password);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result_array();

      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
            $this->session->set_userdata('client_id',$result);

            if($query->row('user_type') == 'admin'){
                redirect('/admins/home');
            }elseif ($query->row('user_type') == 'partner') {
                redirect('/partner/home');
            }else{
                redirect('home');
            }

      }else{
            echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Wrong username or password! </p>";
      }
}
```

**NOTE:** You should separate all your code Model, View and Controller

Comment: thanx buddy. you help me a lot  and yes I will do this.

Comment: Welcome.. Glad to help you.